# Minimal rsync installation without need for cygwin

Tags: windows-xp, rsync

Is there a way to install rsync on Windows XP without having to use cygwin?

I don't want to install cygwin because it takes lot of space.

Moreover, I need to make it communicate with a rsync daemon on Linux, therefore alternatives to rsync on Windows won't help.

Answer (score 7):

Give [RsyncWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rsyncwin32/) a shot.

Comment: I guess there is a native rsync for windows.  I hope it works well.

Comment: How do you install this. Do you first have to `make` it on linux?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the whole cygwin default installation.

You can install cwrsync (see http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650 ).  Cwrsync uses just the minimal set of cygwin files needed to support rsync.

I don't know of a native rsync for windows that doesn't use at least some cygwin files.

Answer (score 1):

DeltaCopy does a similar thing to cwrsync but is particularly focused on windows, and comes with a GUI. It basically packages the cygwin port of rsync together with an ultra-minimal cygwin install. It then wraps a semi-decent windows GUI around it.

Note that I've had some pretty unpleasant troubles with rsync over ssh under windows, so YMMV. Unfortunately there is nothing better for incremental backups. A native version would be nice - there have been many attempts but all have been abandoned, including the above RSyncWin32.